# Are unanswered questions which are duplicates of answered questions counted as answered?

Tags: discussion, support

If it is not in place already, would it make sense to count unanswered questions which are exact duplicates of answered questions as 'answered' so that the count of questions on SO and meta SO reflects the actual number of unanswered questions?

Comment: Closed questions are kinda in a separate category from "unanswered".

Comment: Oh I didn't know that 'marked as duplicate' same as 'closed'. Is that the case?

Comment: Yeah, "duplicate", "on hold", and "closed" are all essentially the same thing.

Comment: Oh ok :) thanks. That would mean that the 50 K questions on meta SO are actual questions, not unanswered duplicates !! This question has been answered now, if you would please put this as an answer so that it is officially. :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closed questions are categorized separately from "unanswered".

Furthermore:

- Duplicate
- Closed
- On Hold

Are all the same thing - that is: a "closed" question.
It's just that "duplicates" get a little icing on the cake in the form of a banner that points to the target.

So no, duplicates will not be counted in the "unanswered" tab.

Comment: So what's the difference between "closed" and "on hold"?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson "On hold" is just a question that's been closed for less than 5? days. The purpose is to convey a sense that it isn't really "closed" yet and it can still be reopened if the question is improved.